# Paste helper - select text to paste from dropdown list

Tags: paste

Is there any tool to hold predefined list of elements to paste, which can be activated by shortcut. For example, when I need to paste my bank account I want to press button, select bank account from list and paste in current input. I know I can bind keyboard shortcuts to many paste commands, but I need to helper window to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zenity`:

Put this in a script and add as keyboard shortcut:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
zenity --list --title="Copy to cliboard" --column=Name --column=Value --print-column=2 \
  "Bank No." "12345678" \
  "Drivers License" "AQ86VC123856"  \
| xclip -selection c
```

Comment: It is also possible to show only *Bank No.* and *Driver License* by adding `--hide-column=2 --hide-header` to `zenity` arguments. For Wayland, `xclip -selection c` can be replaced by `wl-copy`.